# AdventureWorks2012: For each Customer,determine the number of orders created in year 2007,Show 0 for no order

Tags: sql-server-2012

For each customer, determine the number of orders created in year 2007. If a customer has not created any order in year 2007, show 0 for that customer.

Show: customer ID, # of orders created in 2007 (show 0 if none)

Order by: customer ID

Comment: possible duplicate of [AdventureWorks2012: For each customer, determine the number of orders created in year 2007. Show 0 for no order of that customer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702150/adventureworks2012-for-each-customer-determine-the-number-of-orders-created-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - this is the **third time** I'm answering this type of question for you. It seems to me that by now you really should be able to take one of my answers and tweak & adapt it to yet another one of your question - don't you agree?

So here's the one to find the number of sales for each customer in 2007 - showing 0 for those customers who didn't have any sales.

```
-- determine the number of all sales in 2007 for each customer
;WITH SalesPerCustomer AS 
(
    SELECT 
        c.CustomerID,
        NumberOfSales = ISNULL(COUNT(soh.SalesOrderID), 0)
    FROM 
        Sales.Customer c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh ON soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
                                   AND soh.OrderDate >= '20070101' 
                                   AND soh.OrderDate < '20080101'
    GROUP BY    
        c.CustomerID    
)
SELECT 
    CustomerID ,
    NumberOfSales
FROM 
    SalesPerCustomer
ORDER BY 
    NumberOfSales DESC
```